# Can I remove an apostrophe from an SQL search (WHERE clause)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query in SQL (Mysql) using a where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name = 'Bristols';
```

Now I know that there's a row in the table containing  `Bristol's` with an apostrophe, but not one without an apostrophe. However I want to return the row anyway. The problem is that I can only feed the query a value **without** an apostrophe: `Bristols` - is there any way within the query to remove the apostrophe from the field the query is searching?

Comment: put extra single quote, Bristol''s

Comment: Why can you only feed the query a value with an apostrophe? Do you need to know how to escape the single quotes so that you **can** pass the value in with the apostrophe, or is there some other limitation?

Comment: user1502952 If you re-read the question description, it's a bit different to what you think I'm asking. @juergen d has the correct answer below.

Comment: I read the question multiple times, but I'm trying to figure out if you are completely unaware of the concept escaping database inputs (see [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)) or if you actually want the single quote removed.

Comment: @Travesty3 Sorry I was talking to the user1502952 with my last comment. I'm completely aware of escaping inputs, but there's nothing to escape. The input is Bristols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE replace(name, '''', '') = 'Bristols'
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you so much, I never knew that. Everyone else seems to have misunderstood the question, so thank you for getting it spot on!

Comment: In MySQL, wouldn't the solution be `REPLACE(name, '\'', '')`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

#### [See Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2944c/14)

1. Regex:

   ```
   SELECT  * 
   FROM    cities
   WHERE   name REGEXP 'Bristol\'?s';
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   SELECT  * 
   FROM    cities
   WHERE   'Bristols' = replace(name,'\'','');
   ```
3. Explicit Matching:

   ```
   SELECT  * 
   FROM    cities
   WHERE   name IN('Bristols','Bristol''s');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have Two possible outlooks:

First:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE '%Bristol%' // Gather data like: BrISTOLS, Bristols, Bristol, Bristol's,
```

Second:

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE replace(name,'''','') = 'Bristols'
```